# How to give duplicates unique numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table ids like this

```
52
52
53
54
54
54
55
```

I need to find the duplicated and update them like this

```
52   1
52   2
53   1
54   1
54   2
54   3
55   1
```

this query

```
SELECT klient_id,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(klient_id)
    FROM vClient_priklucok
    WHERE klient_id = data.klient_id
  ) AS count
FROM vClient_priklucok AS data
```

returns data like this

```
52   2
52   2
53   1
54   3
54   3
54   3
55   1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,         
       @rownum := case when @prevId <> id then 1 else @rownum + 1 end as rownumber,
       @prevId := id
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prevId := 0) r
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this with variables.  However, you need to be very careful.  A variable should only be referenced in one expression.

In addition, the most recent versions of MySQL require a subquery for ordering the data when you use variables.  So, I would suggest:

```
select t.id,
       (@rn := if(@i = id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@i := id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as counter
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.id
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @i := -1) params;
```

As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) explains:

> In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate
>   @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> **However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined.**